# SPI master to PIC18F4550 slave synchronization (C18) using NETMF

Tags: c, serial-port, interrupt, .net-micro-framework, pic18

A .NET Micro Framework device (ChipworkX in this case) sends a byte through the [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus) interface to a [PIC18F](http://www.automation.com/content/microchip-expands-can-microcontroller-line-with-55v-devices). Having `PIE1bits.SSPIE` enabled, the following code is executed on interrrupt:

```
void high_isr (void)
{
     PIE1bits.SSPIE = 0;
     PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0; //Clear interrupt flag.
     LATDbits.LATD5 = 1; //Enables LED for high interrupt activity.
     while ( !SSPSTATbits.BF ); //Wait until cycle complete
     red_byte_array[1] = SSPBUF;
     SSPBUF = 0x00;
     LATDbits.LATD5 = 0;
     PIE1bits.SSPIE = 1;
}
```

When sending the same byte a few times, the data does not seem to be read consistently. Both master and slave are setup for clock idle low level, and data clocking on rising edge. I don't use the chip select line, because it's direct communictation.
Finally, the master sends data at 100 kHz, while the PIC is operating at 8 MHz.

How do I improve and/or fix this code?

Comment: What are your SSPSTAT and SSPCON1 registers set to? Did you also verify that the SCK, SDO, SDI and ~SS pins are properly configured as input or output? Are you using the ~SS pin?

Answer (score 2):

On the **PIC16F886/7**:

If you are not using the `/SS`, then the data changes on the rising edge and is sampled on the falling edge, for a `SCK` idling at 0: `CKE = 0`, `CKP = 0` (or `1`), `SMP = 0`.

The byte moving from the shift register to the buffer register causes `BF` bit and `SSPIF` the interrupt, so you don't normally loop about in the interrupt waiting for `BF`.

There should not be any need to disable `SSP` interrupts (`SSPIE = 0`), but you probably need to clear the `SSPIF` before returning from interrupt.

I would guess you should, on `SSP` interrupt (`SSPIF = 1`):

`red_byte_array[x] = SSPBUF`
`SSPIF = 0`

You may need to check `WCOL` and `SSPOV` for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your PIC only has ( 8 MHz / 100 kHz ) 80 cycles to respond, that Delay1KTCYx() seems rather long.

Comment: That delay was merely used as a status indicator, keep the led on slightly longer for the human eye be able to witness.